# depth first search in Bash script using simple data structures

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to do as stated above. I have designed a breadth first search with relative ease.

The goal of the script is to create a directory structure of a certain depth and breadth input by the user. I'm trying to alter my breadth first implementation to support depth first search. This is where I got:

```
depthsearch(){

  local open=("seed")
  local tmpopen=()
  local closed=()
  local x="seed"

  for((j=0;j<$depth;j++)); do    

    for x in "${open[@]}" ; do

      for ((i=0;i<$breadth;i++)); do
        tmpopen=("${tmpopen[@]}" "$x/$i")
        mkdir echo "$x/$i"
      done

      open=("${tmpopen[@]}" "${open[@]:1}")

      tmpopen=()
      closed=("${closed[@]}" "$x")

    done

    tmpopen=()

  done

}
```

Okay, so I trimmed down my question a bit. Apparently the problem was that I wasn't iterating by index, so I couldn't update my loop while it was iterating. However, I can't figure out how to iterate by index and update my array so I can construct my directories depth first. Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: It's certainly possible to push and pop bash arrays -- just not efficient. `arr+=( "$item" )` to push and `arr=( "${arr:0:${#arr[@]} - 1}" )` to pop. Alternately, use `"$@"` as your array, push with `set -- "$item" "$@"` and pop with `shift`.

Comment: True, but I don't understand how I can iterate through the array after I push while already in the loop which is what gets me. I'm not familiar enough with bash to do that. I've pushed in the correct order using:
open=("${tmpopen[@]}" "${open[@]:0}"), which also pops off what I'm currently iterating over. But the loop doesn't continue to the first item in the updated open array. It first finished iterating the previous array. What I'm trying to figure out is a different approach for iterating.

Comment: I followed youe example, but I think I'm still having the same problem. Although I'm pushing my depth 1st, I'm still navigating breadth first with x. Also I'm navigating towards the right of the tree instead of the left. Any ideas.

Comment: If you want your iteration to be aware of changes, you need to iterate by index, rather than expanding at the entry to the loop.

Comment: Anyhow -- right now, the scope on this question is too large to make it easy for someone to help. If you could narrow it down to a very simple, tactical problem -- something that could be expressed in just a few lines -- that would be more likely to get a response.

Comment: What prevents you from using `find`?

Comment: I'd prefer to use simple data structures and commands. Find avoids the purpose of this exercise.

Comment: Do you need to use arrays? Maybe a recursive function is easier.

Answer (score 2):

If it is not *strictly necessary* to use data structures, you can do it with a simple recusion:

```
#!/bin/bash
depth=4
breadth=3
node_id=0 #for testing, increments +1 each time a folder is created.

# args: level( [0,depth) ), childNo ( [0,breadth) ) 
generateTreeDFS(){
declare -i level=$1
declare -i childNo=$2
declare -i i=0
    if (( $level < $depth ));then
        mkdir "n_$childNo-$node_id"
        cd "n_$childNo-$node_id"
        let node_id++
        let level++

        while [ $i -lt $breadth ]
        do
            generateTreeDFS $level $i
            let i++
        done
        cd ..
    fi
}
```

If we call

```
generateTreeDFS 0 0
```

The directory structure will be like this:

```
$ tree .

.
├── depthsearch.sh
└── n_0-0
    ├── n_0-1
    │   ├── n_0-2
    │   │   ├── n_0-3
    │   │   ├── n_1-4
    │   │   └── n_2-5
    │   ├── n_1-6
    │   │   ├── n_0-7
    │   │   ├── n_1-8
    │   │   └── n_2-9
    │   └── n_2-10
    │       ├── n_0-11
    │       ├── n_1-12
    │       └── n_2-13
    ├── n_1-14
    │   ├── n_0-15
    │   │   ├── n_0-16
    │   │   ├── n_1-17
    │   │   └── n_2-18
    │   ├── n_1-19
    │   │   ├── n_0-20
    │   │   ├── n_1-21
    │   │   └── n_2-22
    │   └── n_2-23
    │       ├── n_0-24
    │       ├── n_1-25
    │       └── n_2-26
    └── n_2-27
        ├── n_0-28
        │   ├── n_0-29
        │   ├── n_1-30
        │   └── n_2-31
        ├── n_1-32
        │   ├── n_0-33
        │   ├── n_1-34
        │   └── n_2-35
        └── n_2-36
            ├── n_0-37
            ├── n_1-38
            └── n_2-39
```